# find number of tennis matches required

Tags: algorithm

Hi I came across this question from my friend.

Give me a generalised formula to find how many tennis matches (singles) are required for n players ?

Example : if the number of players are 16 then

first : we need 8 mataches (for 16 players) , here 8 players will be eliminated and 8 players will be there

secode : we need 4 matches (for 8 players) , here again 4 players will be eliminated and 4 will be remaining

third : 
 we need 2 matches (for 4 players) , here again 2 players will be eliminated and 2
 will be remaining

Final :
  we need 1 macth to decide a winner among the 2 players

so totally 15 matches are required.

I need a generalised formula to find , such that if I give the value n I should get the number of matches required to find the winner

n may be odd or even

Comment: So what have you got so far? We won't solve the problem for you.

Comment: What you had tried? Post your algorithm

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics and logic, not programming.

Answer (score 5):

For elimination game, the number of matches is always n-1, because one player will be eliminated after one game and n-1 players have to be eliminated in total.

Answer (score 3):

As eventually every player but 1 (the champion) has to lost his match (and every player can lost only in 1 match) then the number of matches required is `n-1`

Comment: if the number of players are 22 how would you solve

Comment: @Chand, if player eliminated after the 1st loss then number of matches is n-1 always - regardless of how the tournament is held. How to organize such tournament with arbitrary number of players is another problem which is not part of the original one it seems.

Comment: but the obvious option is to let some players pass through 1st round without playing and so make number of players in 2nd round 2^k

Answer (score 0):

n-1, because there is one player to leave after each game. and the champion remains