# Find winner in list of tournament matches

Tags: algorithm

I checked for duplicate questions on stackoverflow. This could be close : [find number of tennis matches required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483810/find-number-of-tennis-matches-required)

This is an Amazon interview question. I want to know if Θ(log p) operations on critical path is the right answer to this (On the same lines as tournament barrier algorithm -> John Mellor-Crummey), for 'p' players.

Say for example, we have 4 players 1, 2, 3, 4. We can schedule matches between:

```
 1)  Between (1 & 2)

 2)  Between (3 & 4) 

 3) organize the third match between winners of these two matches.
```

Similarly for 5 (odd number of) players we could schedule matches between:

```
 1) (1 & 2) and (3 & 4) 

 2) Winner from (1&2) OR winner from (3&4) against 5

 3) Winner between winner of not chosen group and winner from previous match
```

.

Comment: So the question is "What is minimal number of matches to win a tournament with `p` players if each match involves two opposing players? Is that number `log(p)`?". Is that the question?

Comment: We don't know what the question was. Voting to close.

Comment: I got it from glassdoor.com, I wish I knew the complete question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every match eliminates exactly one player. To reduce from **p** players to **1** player requries **p-1** matches..

If you are scheduling a maximal number of matches concurrently, with the constraint that a player can participate in only one match at a time, and want to know haw many rounds are required, that is ceiling(log p).

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion. I saw many posts where the answer for (n-1) for players but the constraint wasn't very clear.

Comment: Being an Ah-Ha! question (Obvious and impossible to forget once seen but tricky to recognize initially.), it makes a very poor interview question.